# null is not object(evaluating RNReactNativeDocViewer.openDoc

Tags: react-native

I want to open file from server and show it,and i found library react-native-view-pdf.First of all wanted to see does it work or not,so only copy paste code

react-native link react-native-view-pdf I linked it ,but still doesn’t work

```
const resources = {
  file: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'test-pdf.pdf' : '/sdcard/Download/test-pdf.pdf',
  url: 'https://www.ets.org/Media/Tests/TOEFL/pdf/SampleQuestions.pdf',
  base64: 'JVBERi0xLjMKJcfs...',
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const resourceType = 'base64';

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {/* Some Controls to change PDF resource */}
        <PDFView
          fadeInDuration={250.0}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          resource={resources[resourceType]}
          resourceType={resourceType}
          onLoad={() => console.log(`PDF rendered from ${resourceType}`)}
          onError={() => console.log('Cannot render PDF', error)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

But it does not work and give as title error,can you help me?